# iphone and bluetooth device

Tags: iphone

could i connect my nokia phone to iphone using the following Object..?

1)GKPeerPickerController
2)GKSession

i mean (GameKit)

note that here not two iPhone but it is one iPhone other one is only one Bluetooth device..

thanks and regards
jalju

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a little bit more specific about what your purpose is?
Are you trying to create a cross-platform game or simply transferring data between the devices?

Though the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states that:

> The GKPeerPickerController class
>   provides a standard user interface to
>   allow an iPhone to discover and
>   connect to another iPhone.

So I don't think this is the right way to go.

Comment: my purpose is trasferring data between iPhone and other bluetooth device , (it may be iPhone/ipod touch , any other mobile like nokia samsung or any pc...). is it possible in iPhone programming .